# Error reading a .nc4 file in R (ncdf4 package)

Tags: r, netcdf4

I am trying to use a data set of `.nc4 files` downloaded from [NASA](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/).

The format NCDF4 is confirmed by [this source](http://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/uui/datasets/GLDAS_NOAH025_M_V2.0/summary?keywords=GLDAS_NOAH025_M_2.0&start=1920-01-01&end=2016-10-31#prod-summary). 
I used download .file in R to get the database and then a simple nc_open (ncdf4 package) to test the file. Unfortunately the result is an "Unknown file format" error.

Here my [replication file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4efdbfvqm6arjsy/file.nc4?dl=0) and my script:

```
download.file (url=http://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/.../url, destfile=destination_folder/file.nc4)
```

All fine till this point, but when testing the files:

```
library(ncdf4)
setwd('destination_folder')
data <- nc_open('file.nc4')
Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format
 Error in nc_open("file.nc4") : 
 Error in nc_open trying to open file file.nc4
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what is wrong, but I can add the information that the problem resides in the Windows implementation of the ncdf4 package. With the following statement:

```
catlg<-nc_open("http://opendap.deltares.nl/thredds/dodsC/opendap/rijkswaterstaat/waterbase/concentration_of_suspended_matter_in_water/catalog.nc")
```

I have the same problem as described in the question. However, it works perfectly in R under Linux

The file server is an OpenDAP server strictly following netcdf 4 conventions, but maybe some features are not correctly implemented in the ncdf4 package under Windows

Comment: Thanks Peter. I just sent an email to the developer of the package. I'll post here any solution he might propose.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason I get the same error using [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2), but when using [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3 the ncdf4 package works fine.

not that this solves the problem, but it provides an easy work around for the time being.